# Ошибка  в запроссе

Tags: php, sql

В чем тут ошибка?

```
$a = mysql_query('SELECT id, text, avatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname FROM massage massage join datacenter datacenter on datacenter.id = massage.id_finish WHERE id_start = $id');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a)) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

раз **boolean given** значит ошибка в запросе, я же тебе уже писал - чтобы посмотреть нет ли ошибок запроса пишешь вместо

```
mysql_query('your query here');

mysql_query('your query here') or die(mysql_eror());
```

Посмотри ошибку, поправь запрос, PROFIT...

---

**UPD**

column is ambigious - означает неоднозначность имени колонки таблицы.
Вообщем лечится следующим образом, перепиши текст запроса:

```
SELECT datacenter.id, text, avatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname FROM massage massage join datacenter datacenter on datacenter.id = massage.id_finish WHERE id_start = $id'
```

id - колонка которая есть в обеих таблицах, таким образом чтобы избежать неоднозначно необходимо явно указывать `id` какой именно таблицы ты ищешь.
Естественно если тебе необходим `id` таблицы massage - просто измени `datacenter.id` на `massage.id`

Comment: пишет Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous